# Simple Shell if condition not working

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, file-exists

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo "error"; else echo "success"; fi
```

succeeds, and

```
if [ ! -f index.html ]; then echo "error"; else echo "success"; fi
```

succeeds, but for some reason

```
if [ ! -f index.html ] || [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo "error"; else echo "success"; fi
```

fails.

In my case "index.html" exists and $? = 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if [ ! -f index.html ] || [ $? -ne 0 ]
```

The value of `$?` there reflects the exit code of `[ ! -f index.html ]`.  Since `index.html` exists, that statement results in a nonzero exit code.

Try instead:

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ] || [ ! -f index.html ] ; then echo "error"; else echo "success"; fi
```

Because `[ $? -ne 0 ]` is executed first, the value of `$?` will reflect the exit code of whatever the prior command was and not the result of `[ ! -f index.html ]`.

Another possibility is to put both tests into a single conditional expression:

```
if [ ! -f index.html -o  $? -ne 0 ]; then echo "error"; else echo "success"; fi
```

Because there is a now a single test expression, bash evaluates `$?` before the `! -f index.html` test is run.  Consequently, `$?` will be the exit code of whatever the prior command was.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
if [[ ! -f index.html || $? -ne 0 ]]; then echo "error"; else echo "success"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Every command you execute changes `$?`.  It is best to store this immediately in a new variable and then check it at your leisure.